# Why are some table adapter fields set to ReadOnly and how to overcome

Tags: asp.net, tableadapter

I have a table adapter that uses SP's for all the operations. one of the fields in the Fill and Update is a Timestamp (cast to a bigint and named "VersionNo"), that I use for concurrency checking during update. This field and another called "Name" are both set to ReadOnly for some reason in the table adapter, so every time I change my SP columns and update the adapter they get set to read only and my update fails. I have to remember to change them to ReadOnly = False.

Can anyone explain why they are set to read only and how to fix it so I don't have to update them manually every time I change my db schema? Here's where it fails:

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
 Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
Public Property VersionNo() As Long
    Get
        Try 
            Return CType(Me(Me.tableShipping_Invoice.VersionNoColumn),Long)
        Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
            Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'VersionNo' in table 'Shipping_Invoice' is DBNull.", e)
        End Try
    End Get
    Set
        Me(Me.tableShipping_Invoice.VersionNoColumn) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The column "Name" isn't even used in the update procedure, so I don't know why it's even complaining about that:

```
<UpdateParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$txtVersionNo" PropertyName="Text" Name="VersionNo" Type="Int64" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$txtTripNo" PropertyName="Text" Name="TripNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$ddLineTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="TypeID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$ddVendors" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="VendorID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$txtInvNo" PropertyName="Text" Name="InvNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$txtInvAmount"  PropertyName="Text" Name="InvAmount" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$txtInvDate" PropertyName="Text" Name="InvDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dvInvoice$txtID" PropertyName="Text" Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
```

BLL code

```
    <System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute _
(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, True)> _
    Public Function UpdateInvoiceOC( _
                               TripNo As String, _
                               TypeID As Integer, _
                               VendorID As Integer, _
                               InvNo As String, _
                               InvAmount As Decimal, _
                               InvDate As Date, _
                               ID As Integer, _
                               VersionNo As Long _
                               ) As Boolean

        'STEP 1: Read in the current database product information
        Dim invoices As WolfShipping.Shipping_InvoiceDataTable = Adapter.GetInvoicesByInvoiceID(ID)
        If invoices.Count = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        Dim invoice As WolfShipping.Shipping_InvoiceRow = invoices(0)



        ' invoice.trip contains original values and will be udpated with new value
        invoice.TripNo = TripNo
        invoice.TypeID = TypeID
        invoice.VendorID = VendorID
        invoice.InvNo = InvNo
        invoice.InvAmount = InvAmount
        invoice.InvDate = InvDate
        invoice.ID = ID
        invoice.VersionNo = VersionNo
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = Adapter.Update(invoice)
        ' Return true if precisely one row was updated, otherwise false
        Return rowsAffected = 1



    End Function
```

Comment: Not sure if it would help, you can take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/becbe1e0-4630-4daf-89e6-e9b838dc2bcd/readonly-columns-of-tableadapter-are-being-updated-in-automatically-generated-update-command).

Comment: @afzalulh - thanks for reply. Unfortunately, it's a similar solution: manually edit files every time you updates